# Node S3 is sending me back all objects with similar prefix

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Whenever I'm getting an object in s3 and there's a similar prefix it sends it back. For example, if the prefix is '712' it sends me back the objects for the prefix '7122' also.
How do I only get objects with the exact prefix?

```
 var params = {
                Bucket: "hello",
                Prefix: '712'
            };
s3.listObjectsV2(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                } else {
                    console.log(data)
                  //logs back all similar
                }
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding trailing `/` to the prefix name, like '712/'.

In my test bucket I created two folders: `123` and `1234`

I ran

`aws s3api list-objects-v2 --profile my-profile --prefix "123" --bucket my-test-bucket`

and I got both listed.

Then I ran

`aws s3api list-objects-v2 --profile my-profile --prefix "123/" --bucket my-test-bucket`

and I got only the one with `123` listed

Comment: @YosefYomtobian note that if you had set `Delimiter: '/'` in your original request to indicate that you considered the `/` to be significant, S3 would have returned an array `CommonPrefixes` in the response, one of the members of which would have been `712/`.  No objects would have been listed unless their key both began with `712` and did not contain a subsequent `/` at all.